# bep20 ethers.js transaction under_price

Tags: ethereum, solidity

The code below was working for months and suddenly broke down 2 days ago. I am unsure what happen, the error that was thrown was "message":"transaction underpriced"

It happen for all my wallet, it was working fine previously, I am running for BEP20 BNB Main Chain.

Do advise. Thanks greatly apperciated

```
const sellTokenWithBNB = async (tokenIn, tokenInAmount, tokenOut, tokenOutAmount, account, router) => {
    const tx = await router.swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        tokenInAmount.toString(),
        tokenOutAmount.toString(),
        [tokenIn, tokenOut],
        account.address,
        Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 10, // this txn will be reverted after 10 minutes if not successed
        {
            gasLimit: "30000000",
            gasPrice: await provider.getGasPrice(),
        }
    );
```